# freeswitch can't receive b-leg dtmf during calling to an agent of callcenter for at least 60 seconds

Tags: freeswitch, dtmf

As the title says, I have a problem of getting dtmf digits from b-leg.  When I call a queue in callcenter, the two legs can be bridged. But It doesn't have any reaction when I press '*7' on my b-leg telephone.

Here is the dialplan:

```
    <extension name="Queue90">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^90$">
            <action application="bind_meta_app" data="7 ab s execute_extension::att_xfer XML features"/>
            <action application="callcenter" data="90"/>
        </condition>
    </extension>
```

And, here is the console log:

```
2021-10-28 10:44:19.553594 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1118 New Channel sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 [f3285184-3798-11ec-a026-fd0671809b3f]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.553594 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Running State Change CS_NEW (Cur 1 Tot 3)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.553594 [DEBUG] sofia.c:10279 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 receiving invite from 10.30.4.11:5060 version: 1.10.3 -release 64bit
2021-10-28 10:44:19.553594 [DEBUG] sofia.c:10373 verifying acl "domains" for ip/port 10.30.4.11:0.
2021-10-28 10:44:19.553594 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:604 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State NEW
2021-10-28 10:44:19.573586 [DEBUG] sofia.c:2434 detaching session f3285184-3798-11ec-a026-fd0671809b3f
freeswitch@pbx>
2021-10-28 10:44:19.593597 [DEBUG] sofia.c:2544 Re-attaching to session f3285184-3798-11ec-a026-fd0671809b3f
2021-10-28 10:44:19.613595 [DEBUG] sofia.c:10279 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 receiving invite from 10.30.4.11:5060 version: 1.10.3 -release 64bit
2021-10-28 10:44:19.613595 [DEBUG] sofia.c:10373 verifying acl "domains" for ip/port 10.30.4.11:0.
2021-10-28 10:44:19.613595 [NOTICE] mod_python.c:213 Invoking py module: user_manage
2021-10-28 10:44:19.613595 [DEBUG] mod_python.c:305 Call python script
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] mod_python.c:308 Finished calling python script
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 entering state [received][100]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7335 Remote SDP:
v=0
o=8001 8000 8000 IN IP4 10.30.4.11
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 10.30.4.11
t=0 0
m=audio 5004 RTP/AVP 0 8 9 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ptime:20

2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7738 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State Change CS_NEW -> CS_INIT
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Running State Change CS_INIT (Cur 1 Tot 3)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:628 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State INIT
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:93 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 SOFIA INIT
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:40 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Standard INIT
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:48 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State Change CS_INIT -> CS_ROUTING
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:628 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State INIT going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Running State Change CS_ROUTING (Cur 1 Tot 3)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:2332 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Callstate Change DOWN -> RINGING
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:644 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State ROUTING
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:154 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 SOFIA ROUTING
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:236 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Standard ROUTING
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:637 Processing xxx <8001>->90 in context default
Dialplan: sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 parsing [default->Queue90] continue=false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Regex (PASS) [Queue90] destination_number(90) =~ /^90$/ break=on-false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Action bind_meta_app(7 b s execute_extension::att_xfer XML features)
Dialplan: sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Action callcenter(90)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:287 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State Change CS_ROUTING -> CS_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:644 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State ROUTING going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Running State Change CS_EXECUTE (Cur 1 Tot 3)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:651 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:209 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 SOFIA EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:329 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Standard EXECUTE
EXECUTE [depth=0] sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 bind_meta_app(7 b s execute_extension::att_xfer XML features)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [INFO] switch_ivr_async.c:4457 Bound B-Leg: *7 execute_extension::att_xfer XML features
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:2722 Application callcenter Requires media! pre_answering channel sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [INFO] switch_core_session.c:2724 Sending early media
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5647 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5647 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5647 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5508 Set telephone-event payload to 101@8000
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:3837 Set Codec sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 PCMU/8000 20 ms 160 samples 64000 bits 1 channels
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_codec.c:111 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Original read codec set to PCMU:0
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5851 Set telephone-event payload to 101@8000
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5909 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Set 2833 dtmf send payload to 101 recv payload to 101
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:8661 AUDIO RTP [sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77] 10.75.6.77 port 30308 -> 10.30.4.11 port 5004 codec: 0 ms: 20
2021-10-28 10:44:19.633586 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:4413 Starting timer [soft] 160 bytes per 20ms
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:8975 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Set 2833 dtmf send payload to 101
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:8982 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Set 2833 dtmf receive payload to 101
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:9005 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Set rtp dtmf delay to 40
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [NOTICE] sofia_media.c:92 Pre-Answer sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77!
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3565 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Callstate Change RINGING -> EARLY
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:8643 Audio params are unchanged for sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77.
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:2593 Ring SDP:
v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1635358751 1635358752 IN IP4 10.75.6.77
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 10.75.6.77
t=0 0
m=audio 30308 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

EXECUTE [depth=0] sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 callcenter(90)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 entering state [early][183]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:8643 Audio params are unchanged for sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77.
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:898 Local SDP sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77:
v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1635358751 1635358753 IN IP4 10.75.6.77
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 10.75.6.77
t=0 0
m=audio 30308 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [NOTICE] mod_callcenter.c:3020 Channel [sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77] has been answered
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3865 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Callstate Change EARLY -> ACTIVE
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 entering state [completed][200]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:3111 Member xxx <8001> joining queue 90
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:3375 Queue has 1 waiting calls.
2021-10-28 10:44:19.653601 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_play_say.c:1488 Codec Activated L16@8000hz 1 channels 20ms
freeswitch@pbx>
2021-10-28 10:44:19.673591 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:1180 Updated Agent 5001 set state = Receiving
2021-10-28 10:44:19.673591 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:1753 Setting outbound caller_id_name to: xxx
2021-10-28 10:44:19.673591 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:2242 Parsing global variables
2021-10-28 10:44:19.673591 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:2804 Parsing session specific variables
2021-10-28 10:44:19.673591 [NOTICE] mod_python.c:213 Invoking py module: user_manage
2021-10-28 10:44:19.673591 [DEBUG] mod_python.c:305 Call python script
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] mod_python.c:308 Finished calling python script
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:2242 Parsing global variables
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1118 New Channel sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 [f33da75a-3798-11ec-a02f-fd0671809b3f]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:5089 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State Change CS_NEW -> CS_INIT
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Running State Change CS_INIT (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:628 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State INIT
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:93 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 SOFIA INIT
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] sofia_glue.c:1587 sip:5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Setting proxy route to sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] sofia_glue.c:1618 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 sending invite version: 1.10.3 -release 64bit
Local SDP:
v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1635364719 1635364720 IN IP4 10.75.6.77
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 10.75.6.77
t=0 0
m=audio 24340 RTP/AVP 102 9 0 8 105 101
a=rtpmap:102 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:102 useinbandfec=1; maxaveragebitrate=30000; maxplaybackrate=48000; ptime=20; minptime=10; maxptime=40
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:105 telephone-event/48000
a=fmtp:105 0-16
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
m=video 25832 RTP/AVP 103 104
b=AS:3072
a=rtpmap:103 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:104 VP8/90000
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-fb:103 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:103 ccm tmmbr
a=rtcp-fb:103 nack
a=rtcp-fb:103 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:104 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:104 ccm tmmbr
a=rtcp-fb:104 nack
a=rtcp-fb:104 nack pli

2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:40 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Standard INIT
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:48 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State Change CS_INIT -> CS_ROUTING
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:628 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State INIT going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Running State Change CS_ROUTING (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:644 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State ROUTING
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:154 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 SOFIA ROUTING
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:67 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State Change CS_ROUTING -> CS_CONSUME_MEDIA
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:644 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State ROUTING going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Running State Change CS_CONSUME_MEDIA (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:663 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State CONSUME_MEDIA
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:663 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State CONSUME_MEDIA going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:19.693596 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 entering state [calling][0]
freeswitch@pbx>
freeswitch@pbx>
2021-10-28 10:44:19.833592 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 entering state [proceeding][180]
2021-10-28 10:44:19.833592 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7436 Ring-Ready sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068!
2021-10-28 10:44:19.833592 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3437 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Callstate Change DOWN -> RINGING
freeswitch@pbx>
freeswitch@pbx>
2021-10-28 10:44:19.973606 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 entering state [ready][200]
2021-10-28 10:44:20.253590 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:7722 Correct audio ip/port confirmed.
freeswitch@pbx>
2021-10-28 10:44:22.173587 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_play_say.c:1933 done playing file /usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/zhuanjiezhong.wav
2021-10-28 10:44:22.193590 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_play_say.c:1488 Codec Activated L16@8000hz 1 channels 20ms
2021-10-28 10:44:23.053590 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 entering state [completing][200]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.053590 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7335 Remote SDP:
v=0
o=5001 8004 8000 IN IP4 10.30.0.15
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 10.30.0.15
t=0 0
m=audio 5028 RTP/AVP 0 8 9 105
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:105 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:105 0-15
a=ptime:20
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 103 104

2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 entering state [ready][200]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5647 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5647 Audio Codec Compare [PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5647 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5592 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5508 Set telephone-event payload to 105@8000
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:3837 Set Codec sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 PCMU/8000 20 ms 160 samples 64000 bits 1 channels
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_codec.c:111 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Original read codec set to PCMU:0
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5851 Set telephone-event payload to 105@8000
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:5909 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Set 2833 dtmf send payload to 105 recv payload to 101
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:8661 AUDIO RTP [sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068] 10.75.6.77 port 24340 -> 10.30.0.15 port 5028 codec: 0 ms: 20
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:4413 Starting timer [soft] 160 bytes per 20ms
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:8975 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Set 2833 dtmf send payload to 105
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:8982 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Set 2833 dtmf receive payload to 101
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:9005 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Set rtp dtmf delay to 40
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [NOTICE] sofia.c:8503 Channel [sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068] has been answered
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3865 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Callstate Change RINGING -> ACTIVE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3852 Originate Resulted in Success: [sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.073610 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3852 Originate Resulted in Success: [sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068]
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_async.c:1351 Record session sample rate: 8000 -> 8000
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_core_media_bug.c:970 Attaching BUG to sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:1965 Agent 5001 answered "xxx" <8001> from queue 90 (Recorded)
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:2213 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State Change CS_EXECUTE -> CS_HIBERNATE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:2215 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State Change CS_CONSUME_MEDIA -> CS_HIBERNATE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Running State Change CS_HIBERNATE (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:666 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State HIBERNATE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:191 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 SOFIA HIBERNATE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1144 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State Change CS_HIBERNATE -> CS_RESET
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:666 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State HIBERNATE going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Running State Change CS_RESET (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:647 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State RESET
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:172 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 SOFIA RESET
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1129 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 CUSTOM RESET
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:188 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Standard RESET
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:647 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State RESET going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_play_say.c:1933 done playing file /usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/zhuanjiezhong.wav
2021-10-28 10:44:23.093582 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:3283 Member xxx <8001> is answered by an agent in queue 90
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:3375 Queue has 0 waiting calls.
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:651 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State EXECUTE going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Running State Change CS_HIBERNATE (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:666 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State HIBERNATE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:191 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 SOFIA HIBERNATE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1144 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State Change CS_HIBERNATE -> CS_RESET
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:666 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State HIBERNATE going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Running State Change CS_RESET (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:647 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State RESET
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:172 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 SOFIA RESET
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1129 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 CUSTOM RESET
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1136 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State Change CS_RESET -> CS_SOFT_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:647 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State RESET going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) Running State Change CS_SOFT_EXECUTE (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:657 (sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77) State SOFT_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:662 SOFIA SOFT_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1154 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 CUSTOM SOFT_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1186 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State Change CS_RESET -> CS_SOFT_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Running State Change CS_SOFT_EXECUTE (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:657 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State SOFT_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:662 SOFIA SOFT_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1154 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 CUSTOM SOFT_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:401 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Standard SOFT_EXECUTE
2021-10-28 10:44:23.113588 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:657 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State SOFT_EXECUTE going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1683 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State Change CS_SOFT_EXECUTE -> CS_CONSUME_MEDIA
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Running State Change CS_CONSUME_MEDIA (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:663 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State CONSUME_MEDIA
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1058 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 CUSTOM HOLD
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:663 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State CONSUME_MEDIA going to sleep
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_bridge.c:1793 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State Change CS_CONSUME_MEDIA -> CS_EXCHANGE_MEDIA
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:585 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) Running State Change CS_EXCHANGE_MEDIA (Cur 2 Tot 4)
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:654 (sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068) State EXCHANGE_MEDIA
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:656 SOFIA EXCHANGE_MEDIA
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:2009 Member "xxx" 8001 is bridged to agent 5001
2021-10-28 10:44:23.133586 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_async.c:1640 No silence detection configured; assuming start of speech
2021-10-28 10:44:23.153585 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:1301 Updated tier: Agent 5001 in Queue 90 set state = Active Inbound
2021-10-28 10:44:23.153585 [DEBUG] mod_callcenter.c:1180 Updated Agent 5001 set state = In a queue call
2021-10-28 10:44:23.153585 [DEBUG] switch_core_io.c:448 Setting BUG Codec PCMU:0
2021-10-28 10:44:23.293594 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:7722 Correct audio ip/port confirmed.
freeswitch@pbx>
freeswitch@pbx>
freeswitch@pbx>
freeswitch@pbx>
freeswitch@pbx>
2021-10-28 10:45:20.773590 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 entering state [calling][0]
2021-10-28 10:45:20.813595 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 entering state [completing][200]
2021-10-28 10:45:20.813595 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7335 Remote SDP:
v=0
o=5001 8004 8001 IN IP4 10.30.0.15
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 10.30.0.15
t=0 0
m=audio 5028 RTP/AVP 0 8 9 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ptime:20
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 103

2021-10-28 10:45:20.833591 [DEBUG] sofia.c:7325 Channel sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 entering state [ready][200]
2021-10-28 10:45:26.813594 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:7967 RTP RECV DTMF *:1280
2021-10-28 10:45:26.813594 [INFO] switch_channel.c:522 RECV DTMF *:1280
2021-10-28 10:45:27.233594 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:7967 RTP RECV DTMF 7:1280
2021-10-28 10:45:27.233594 [INFO] switch_channel.c:522 RECV DTMF 7:1280
2021-10-28 10:45:27.233594 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_async.c:4311 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Processing meta digit '7' [execute_extension::att_xfer XML features]
2021-10-28 10:45:27.533627 [DEBUG] switch_ivr.c:632 sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 Command Execute [depth=0] playback(local_stream://moh)
EXECUTE [depth=0] sofia/internal/8001@10.75.6.77 playback(local_stream://moh)
2021-10-28 10:45:27.533627 [DEBUG] switch_ivr.c:632 sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 Command Execute [depth=0] execute_extension(att_xfer XML features)
EXECUTE [depth=0] sofia/internal/5001@10.30.0.15:5068 execute_extension(att_xfer XML features)
```

But I can capture the dtmf packet from my telephone. It's so weird to me. Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to fix it now.
It's cause by freeswitch set 2833 dtmf send payload to 105 recv payload to 101, but the telephone still send 105 dtmf payload type to freeswitch.
I modified 'rfc2833-pt' in sip_profiles/internal.xml to '105' and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because DTMF use the RFC-2833, so you should check your `sip_profiles/*.xml` to find whether you set the `rfc2833-pt` value also check [FreeSWITCH configuration](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/DTMF)